# Facebook like button callback

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook

When clicking a button like the 'like' button on Facebook, the like seems immediately (read: instantly) executed.

How is the user guaranteed that the Ajax call actually succeeded?
Is the 'like' visible at the client only executed as a response of the server?
Visually, it seems to happen instantly and I've never experienced it otherwise.

The response from the server after clicking 'like', looks like a bunch of code that I don't understand:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read this question yesterday and then today Facebook's ajax failed!

Under a Facebook picture, the like button changed from "like" to "unlike", and then quickly changed back.

Then a dialog box box called "Try Again Soon" popped up, saying "Sorry there is a temporary problem with this post. Please try again in a few moments."

So that's what ensures the user won't just scroll past the error.

Answer (score 1):

They assume that if the like button is displayed it will be possible to like it. If something goes wrong in the backend the like button will change back from Liked to Like.

Comment: Never experienced this before. Strange solution though; what happens when the user likes something, continues scrolling while something goes wrong, and doesn't notice when the 'like' jumps back to normal?

Comment: I upvoted your reply. Sorry for not accepting, even though it was correct. I tend to accept the most complete one as it will be the most complete help for future visitors. Thanks again.